# Tabs+Swipe in Android for all API levels

Tags: java, android, actionbarsherlock

My plan is creating an Activity includes Tabs+Swipe for all Android version. If we set it from a default Android project, it has just support for at least API 11.

In [Sherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) we have two project named : Tab Navigation, Tab Navigation(collapsed) includes Tabs but not Swipe.
They have Issue #240 in their samples that has a bug (swipe left/right when the tabs are in collapsed mode (landscape) and the selected item does not update).

Do you know any sample code that solve this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I also happened to have same situation. Follow below links and you will get all what you need.

See this tutorial
http://droidista.blogspot.com/2012/08/making-actionbarsherlock-and.html

And get demo code from here
https://github.com/zmdominguez/vpi-abs-demo

Answer (score 8):

You made this now with the default Android Support Library (or the ABS), with a `ViewPager` and a `PagerTabStrip`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
            android:id="@+id/tabStrip"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"/>

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>

</LinearLayout>
```

Then create an `Adapter` to the `ViewPager` that extends of `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` (for example) and override the method `public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position)` to provide a title for each tab.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

I found these links which might help you out.

1. [A page flipper control - like the android home screens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5052324/a-page-flipper-control-like-the-android-home-screens)
2. https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator